# color polygon boundaries by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to highlight zones on a map based on an associated factor, like so:

[image]

My initial problem was that, because the boundaries are overlapping, the zones would display improperly, like this:

[image]

I fixed that by hackily subsetting the data, which resulted in the first picture.

```
#First Map With No Legend    
p <- ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data = OpportunityAreas.df[OpportunityAreas.df$Opp_Area == 'Yes',],
                   aes(long,lat,group=group), fill = "#d2eef7", color = 'black') +
      geom_polygon(data = OpportunityAreas.df[OpportunityAreas.df$Opp_Area == 'No',],
                   aes(long,lat,group=group), fill = "#d2eef7", color = 'orange') +
      coord_map()
```

But now I have no legend and also it just seems like a poor solution. Is there a proper way to color polygon boundaries by an associated factor?

```
#Second Map With Improper Boundaries
    p.improperly.drawn <- ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data = OpportunityAreas.df,
                   aes(long,lat,group=group, color = Opp_Area), fill = "#d2eef7") +
      coord_map()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first solution needs only a small tweak to get what you are looking for: move the `color` arguments within the `geom_polygon` calls to a `mapping = aes()` call instead.  For the first call, `mapping = aes(color = 'black')` and for the second `geom_polygon` call use `mapping = aes(color = 'orange')`.

I do not have access to the `OpportunityAreas.df` in your example so I will use some generic mapping data for my example below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mapdata)

counties <- map_data("county")
ca_county <- subset(counties, region == "california")
ca_county$color <- cut(ca_county$group, 2, labels = c("A", "B"))

ggplot() +
  aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group) + 
  geom_polygon(data = subset(ca_county, color == "A"),
               mapping = aes(color = "A"),
               fill = NA) +
  geom_polygon(data = subset(ca_county, color == "B"),
               mapping = aes(color = "B"),
               fill = NA)
```

[image]